# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar align not working properly

Tags: php, model-view-controller, content-management-system, navbar

im generating a bootstrap navbar using codeigniter, its working fine but i want the admin link to be aligned to the right. here is my code:

```
    function get_menu ($array, $child = FALSE)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $str = '';

    if (count($array)) {
        $str .= $child == FALSE ? '<ul class="nav navbar-left navbar-custom">' . PHP_EOL : '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

        foreach ($array as $item) {

            $active = $CI->uri->segment(1) == $item['slug'] ? TRUE : FALSE;
            if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
                $str .= $active ? '<li class="dropdown active">' : '<li class="dropdown">';
                $str .= '<a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="' . site_url(e($item['slug'])) . '">' . e($item['title']);
                $str .= '<b class="caret"></b></a>' . PHP_EOL;
                $str .= get_menu($item['children'], TRUE);
            }
            else {
                $str .= $active ? '<li class="active">' : '<li>';
                $str .= '<a href="' . site_url($item['slug']) . '">' . e($item['title']) . '</a>';

            }

                // Closing tags
            $str .= '</li>' ;
        }
                //add dashboard link to the right of menu for login
        $str .= '<li>' . '<p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><a 
    `href="admin/dashboard" class="navbar-link"> ADMIN</a></p></li>' . PHP_EOL; 

        $str .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

im getting a navbar with required links but its all inline. any help is aappreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is because of where you are adding the `navbar-right` class. You have to add it to an `ul` element. Change your second to last string:

```
$str .= '<li>' . '<p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><a `href="admin/dashboard" class="navbar-link"> ADMIN</a></p></li>' . PHP_EOL;
```

To something along these lines:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="admin/dashboard" class="navbar-link"> ADMIN</a></li>
</ul>
```

And do not add it inside of your current `ul` element, that will also not work; you need to close the `navbar-left` class then add the `navbar-right`.

Looking something like this:

### UPDATE

I think I got it, you do not have the `nav` element around your navbar, and that is probably what is causing the issues with alignments...

```
<?php
function get_menu ($array, $child = FALSE)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $str = '';

    if (count($array)) {
        $str .= $child == FALSE ? '<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-custom">' . PHP_EOL; // create the <nav> element

        foreach ($array as $item) {

            $active = $CI->uri->segment(1) == $item['slug'] ? TRUE : FALSE;
            if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
                $str .= $active ? '<li class="dropdown active">' : '<li class="dropdown">';
                $str .= '<a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="' . site_url(e($item['slug'])) . '">' . e($item['title']);
                $str .= '<b class="caret"></b></a>' . PHP_EOL;
                $str .= get_menu($item['children'], TRUE);
            }
            else {
                $str .= $active ? '<li class="active">' : '<li>';
                $str .= '<a href="' . site_url($item['slug']) . '">' . e($item['title']) . '</a>';

            }

                // Closing tags
            $str .= '</li>' ;
        }

        $str .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

        //add dashboard link to the right of menu for login
        $str .= '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="admin/dashboard" class="navbar-link"> ADMIN</a></li>
                </ul>' . PHP_EOL;

        // add the nav closing tag
        $str .= '</nav>' . PHP_EOL;

    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, It has made a difference however its still left aligned, I shall keep playing around and post a fix if i find it

Comment: I'm sorry man, what version of Bootstrap are you currently using?

Comment: Thanks for the help, im using the latest bootstrap (3.3.7) ad the latest codeigniter (3.1.5)